# Error in augment function for lasso models

Tags: r, glmnet, tidymodels

**Background**

I have a data set on which I have fitted a lasso model using the `tidymodels` package. Now, I have artificially created a new data set on which I would like to use this model to make predictions. This is a classifications exercise, where I have 10 predictors trying to determine 1 binary variable.

**Issue**

When I use `augment(extract_fit_parsnip(lasso_final_fit), new_data = new_investors) %>% glimpse()`, R throws me the following error: `Error in new_data[, rownames(object$fit$beta), drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds`.

My model was coded as follows:

```
log_rec <- recipe(defensive ~ ., data = modelling_train) %>%
  step_select(-date) %>%
  step_novel(all_nominal_predictors()) %>% 
  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors()) %>% 
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors())
lasso_final_spec <- logistic_reg(engine = "glmnet",
                                 penalty = 0.03,
                                 mixture = 1)
lasso_final_wf <- workflow(preprocessor = log_rec,
                           spec = lasso_final_spec)
lasso_final_fit <- last_fit(lasso_final_wf,
                            split = modelling_split,
                            metrics = metric_set(accuracy, sens, spec, roc_auc))
```

My `new_investors` data set was created as follows:

```
new_investors <- data.frame(sex = as.factor(sample(c("female", "male"), 100, T)),
                            date = as_date(sample(c("2020-03-15", "2021-03-15"), 100, T)),
                            age = sample(seq(min(modelling %>% pull(age)),
                                             max(modelling %>% pull(age))), 100, T),
                            tx = sample(seq(min(modelling %>% pull(tx)),
                                            max(modelling %>% pull(tx))), 100, T),
                            risk_before = sample(c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1), 100, T),
                            risk_after = sample(c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1), 100, T),
                            fund_value = rnorm(100, mean(cleaned %>% pull(fund_value), na.rm = T),
                                               sd(cleaned %>% pull(fund_value), na.rm = T)))
```

1. I have compared `new_investors` to `modelling_train` and am very sure that the predictors I used in the model are all contained within `new_investors`. Column names are the same as well.
2. I saw elsewhere that the `predict` function only accepts `data.matrix` data sets, so I tried that as well, but it did not work too.
3. As an extension of this exercise, I was also required to build a random forest model, yet when I use the exact same `new_investors` data set in the `augment` code for this model, the predictions come out perfectly fine.

I must also apologise in advance for not producing an MWE. I know this is what is usually needed, but I am not sure how to produce an MWE in this case.

What could possibly be the issue here? Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without the data but I think that you need to make predictions from the workflow. Using just the parsnip fit avoids preprocessing with the recipe. As a result, your model fit gets different data (sometimes silently) than what it should have gotten if the data were processed with the recipe.

Here's an example:

```r
library(tidymodels)

data("two_class_dat")

set.seed(1)
split <- initial_split(two_class_dat)

lasso_final_spec <- logistic_reg(engine = "glmnet",
                                 penalty = 0.03,
                                 mixture = 1)
lasso_final_wf <- workflow(preprocessor = Class ~ .,
                           spec = lasso_final_spec)
lasso_final_fit <- last_fit(lasso_final_wf,
                            split = split,
                            metrics = metric_set(accuracy, sens, spec, roc_auc))

# Get the fitted workflow out
lasso_final_wflow <- 
  lasso_final_fit %>% 
  extract_workflow()

set.seed(2)
new_dat <- tibble(A = runif(3), B = runif(3))
lasso_final_wflow %>% augment(new_dat) 
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>       A     B .pred_class .pred_Class1 .pred_Class2
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>              <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 0.185 0.168 Class1             0.945       0.0554
#> 2 0.702 0.944 Class1             0.775       0.225 
#> 3 0.573 0.943 Class1             0.771       0.229
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Also, `glance()` pulls things out of the fitted model so you can't use that on a set of new predictions. I suggest saving your metric set as an object and use it to evaluate these predictions (assuming you know their labels)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer! This actually solved the problem, but now I have two more queries, if you do not mind... Firstly, why would `extract_fit_parsnip()` work for `augment` on a random forest model but not on a lasso model? Do you think this is a potential "bug"? Secondly, could you elaborate on `glance()`? I am pretty new to `tidyverse` and am not sure what it is used for.